# How To Pass Variable To Pepper-Box Plain Text Config

Tags: java, apache-kafka, jmeter

I'm setting up my Pepper-Box Plain text Config to Pass variable using `${accountNumber}, ${{accountNumber}}, {{accountNumber}}`, and using function to return string, but it didn't work.

**This is my message to kafka :**

```
{
    "eventName": "OFFER",
    "payload": {
        "accountNumber": "${accountNumber}",
        "Limit": 20000000
  }
}
```

but the variable didn't pass, when I see the debug sampler, the accountNumber is pass.
I think there is mistake when I call the variable, but I try some techniques but it didnt work too.

The **error Message** when I try `${{accountNumber}}` is :

> symbol:   method accountNumber()
>     location: class MessageIterator1566802574812
>   1 error
>
> Uncaught Exception java.lang.ClassFormatError: Truncated class file. See log file for details.

Comment: From where are you taking ${accountNumber}? Use only ${accountNumber} not with {{}}.

Comment: It's not working, The variable not substitute in the message too, I read an question too in SO, and they try using that way.
Is there is something needed to pass the variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a limitation of the plugin, you're basically limited to [Schema Template Functions](https://github.com/GSLabDev/pepper-box#schema-template-functions)

Alternatively you can send a record to Kafka using [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and the following Groovy code:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterVariables
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord

def kafkaProps = new Properties()
kafkaProps.put(org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092")
kafkaProps.put(org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "KafkaExampleProducer")
kafkaProps.put(org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.LongSerializer.class.getName())
kafkaProps.put(org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer.class.getName())
def producer = new KafkaProducer<>(kafkaProps)

JMeterVariables vars = new JMeterVariables()
vars.put("accountNumber", "foo")

def record = new ProducerRecord<>("test", "{\n" +
        "    \"eventName\": \"OFFER\",\n" +
        "    \"payload\": {\n" +
        "        \"accountNumber\": \"" + vars.get("accountNumber") + "\",\n" +
        "        \"Limit\": 20000000\n" +
        "  }\n" +
        "}")

producer.send(record)
```

More information: [Apache Kafka - How to Load Test with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-kafka-how-to-load-test-with-jmeter/)

Comment: That's working @Dmitri T !
I thinking that's the limitation of the plugin too, because variable just cant call in that section. 
Thank you Dmitri :D